# JavaScript upload multiple images

Tags: javascript, image, upload

I have 2 upload buttons on same admin page (wordpress). Separately, they works perfect. But together, they don't work as it should. I'm sure it's from the JavaScript file because if I remove the code lines from one button, the other one works.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#upload_logo_button').click(function() {
        tb_show('Upload a logo', 'media-upload.php?referer=wptuts-settings&amp;type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true&amp;post_id=0', false);
        return false;
    });
    window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
        var image_url = $('img',html).attr('src');
        $('#logo_url').val(image_url);
        tb_remove();
        $('#upload_logo_preview img').attr('src',image_url);
        $('#submit_options_form').trigger('click');
    }

    $('#upload_banner_button').click(function() {
        tb_show('Upload a banner', 'media-upload.php?referer=wptuts-settings&amp;type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true&amp;post_id=0', false);
        return false;
});

    window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
        var img_url = $('img',html).attr('src');
        $('#banner_url').val(img_url);
        tb_remove();
        $('#upload_banner_preview img').attr('src',img_url);
        $('#submit_options_form').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: That's because you're redefining the `window.send_to_editor` function (you can't have two properties with the same name), I don't know how/where that is called so I can't provide you with a viable solution

Comment: @smokro, was your issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You have two `window.send_to_editor` functions. Can you rename them to be separate—or better yet, combine them (possibly passing in as another argument the `#logo_url`/`#banner_url` selector)?